# How is it possible to have MySQL Keyring plugin to connect to AWS KMS services?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, encryption, key-management

I'm trying to find a solution where I can leverage MySQL Keyring plugin to activate the data at rest encryption for InnoDB but using AWS Key Management system. I found a similar plugin for MariaDB but I cannot find the same thing for MySQL:

[MariaDB's AWS KMS encryption plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-enterprise-aws-kms-encryption-plugin-setup-guide/)

Or I have to build it from scratch?

Comment: Did you read this http://www.awsomeblog.com/aws-rds-encryption-at-rest/

Comment: Yes, but we are not using AWS RDS, we are install MySQL in our machines and we are trying to leverage AWS KMS. If we were to choose AWS RDS, then I wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: I have the exact same question - did you find any answers? (or have you attempted this from scratch?)

Comment: Hi Paddy, I asked Percona to see if they have a solution on that; they replied saying that they don't support it for now and the only solution is to use Oracle's keyring. I object that idea because then I'd rather just get Oracle's DBs. 

Another solution is to build myself, but I don't have the time for that. :(

Comment: Only MySQL Enterprise which comes with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) feature has the plugins to work with AWS Key Management Service.  The community version does not offer this functionality.  The plugin name is "keyring_aws.so" for linux or "keyring_aws.dll" for windows.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/keyring-installation.html